# Cannot edit subscriptions after renaming Reporting Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

We had to rename a reporting server. (OLD_SERVERNAME --> NEW_SERVERNAME)
This is a Windows 2012 R2 server with SQL 2014 Standard installed.
That went ok.  But now we are adding subscriptions.
Subscriptions I added canot be found under 'My Subscriptions'
However, If I go to manage the report and choose 'Subsdcriptions' I can see the subscriptions I made.
If I try to edit them however I get an error stating:

```
The user or group name 'OLD_SERVERNAME\henro' is not recognized. (rsUnknownUserName) Get Online Help
```

That would explain why I do not see the subscriptions since I am logged in as 'NEW_SERVERNAME\henro' but why are those new subscriptions made by NEW_SERVERNAME\henro connected to the user OLD_SERVERNAME\henro?
And more important, how do I solve this so that I can manage subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change you made to the server did not propagate to the ssrs user database. Actually, you can log into ssrs manager and change all the users with OLD_SERVER/UN to NEW_SERVER/UN and that should work.

Comment: UPDATE [dbo].[Users]
   SET [UserName] =replace(username, 'OLD_SERVER','NEW_SERVER')
GO  did the trick very well (and fast)